# Blender multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, segmentation-fault, blender

I am trying to create a simple project in which the position of a certain object is updated in a specific thread while in the others data are received from an UDP client. But now, for simplicity, I am testing only the thread related to the visual update of the object position.

The problem is that every time I run the code, after a while it gives me a segmentation fault error. The code is here reported

```
def robot_handler(self):
    with ThreadLoop.event() as event: # this part required for closing the thread
        while not event.is_set():  #
            for i in range(ROBOT_NUMBER):
                #update of the object position
                self.robotic_line[i].target.matrix_world.translation[0] += 5
            time.sleep(1/REFRESH_RATE)
```

The thread is simply launched in the main by

```
self.__robot_thread = Thread(target=self.robot_handler, name='robot', args=())
self.__robot_thread.start()
```